# create a GitHub repository from node-js

Tags: node.js, github-api

I want to be able to create a GitHub repository and to be able to commit and push from my NodeJS application.

I have searched a lot for a working example but I haven't found it yet.

Can anyone recommend libraries with documentation I can look at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Can the [Github api](https://developer.github.com/libraries/) help you?

You can find the nodejs library such as [this one](https://github.com/pksunkara/octonode)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a Github client written for Node. https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github looks pretty solid, as it covers most of the API. Here's a sample documentation link: http://mikedeboer.github.io/node-github/#repos.prototype.create